# How to share HAProxy configurations between two servers

Tags: replication, haproxy

I have a HAProxy servers that redirect my front IP server to multiple internal servers but my primary concern now is if the server containing HAProxy stops working.

The simple way would be to setup the same server, but **there's a twist** : I manage the HAProxy server from code (via a webui/api) and the configuration changes quite often.

So I'm looking to find a way, if possible, to have some kind of replication of the HAProxy configuration (like MySQL for example) or if there is that kind of system for any other proxy like service ?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lsyncd which allow to synchronise files or directories from a server to an other.
I use it with many gigs of data without issues.

Lsyncd can be found here : https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd